# How to coerce an extended builtin type back to a builtin

Tags: go

I am trying to coerce an extended builtin type back to its original builtin type for purposes of using it for Mathematical operation.

Below is a toy example of what I'm trying to do that illustrates my problem. `valueType1` extends string and `valueType2` extends int.

I'm given the error

> impossible type assertion: int does not implement Value (missing DoThing method)

Given an array of interface `Value`, is there any way to determine if the passed `Value` is an integer and then cast it back as such for *actual* math purposes?

Changing the coercion to `if w, ok := interface{}(v).(int); ok {` compiles successfully but *does not work*.

**Note** - With this toy example, I could absolutely add a separate method `func (v valueType2) GetValue() int` and type coerce or cast against the specific `valueType2` type. The problem in actuality is that the specific *non-interface* types are in a different package and **not exported**. Only the `Value` interface is exported, and I don't have access to change said package.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Value interface {
    DoThing()
}

type valueType1 string

func (v valueType1) DoThing() {
    fmt.Println(v, "is a pretty sweet string")
}

type valueType2 int

func (v valueType2) DoThing() {
    fmt.Println(v, "is a pretty sweet int")
}

func main() {
    var x valueType1 = "foo"
    var y valueType2 = 10

    z := []Value{x, y}

    for _, v := range z {
        if w, ok := v.(int); ok {
            fmt.Println(w)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.17.2) package to determine the [*kind*](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.17.2#Kind) of a type. Once you know the kind you can use the corresponding getter (in your case [`(reflect.Value).Int()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.17.2#Value.Int)) to get an instance of the value in the builtin type.

Note that, since `Int()` returns an `int64` value and you need an `int` value, additionally you will need to do an explicit conversion.

```golang
if rv := reflect.ValueOf(v); rv.Kind() == reflect.Int {
    w := int(rv.Int())
    fmt.Printf("%v type=%T", w, w)
}
```